# WPF DataGrid вызвать событие MouseDoubleClick при нажатии Enter на строке

Tags: wpf, datagrid

В DataGrid есть событие `MouseDoubleClick` на строке с обработчиком. Как его вызвать при нажатии Enter? По умолчанию Enter переводит курсор на следующую строку

Comment: А как вы пробовали и что не получилось?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я не нашел способа попробовать. Искал подобие `datagrid.MouseDoubleClick.call()` но такого нет

Answer (score 0):

Решение:
Пришлось вынести логику в отдельный метод и вызывать
`MouseDoubleClick="log_grid_MouseDoubleClick"`
`PreviewKeyDown="Log_grid_PreviewKeyDown"`

```
private void Log_grid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        showDataGridRow();
    }
}

private void log_grid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    showDataGridRow();
}
```